# PHP: Using Static Variable as Method Parameter

Tags: php, static-variables

Here is a Trait:

```
trait Status
{
    public static $_ACTIVE = 1;
    public static $_INACTIVE = 0;
}
```

How can I use variables from **Status** trait to my class method parameter?

```
class User
{
    public function getUser($status = Status::$_ACTIVE) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't, use __constants__ instead. But traits cannot have constants, that's sad.

Comment: You cant use static variable as default value for parameter or any variable for that matter. Use consts. Why Status is even a trait? Change Status to class or interface, add consts for ACTIVE / INACTIVE and use them as Status::ACTIVE